# Pulling API data with jQuery and AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, symfony

I am working on pulling API data inside a form in my internship Symfony2 project.
I have to pin on an API to insert data when a person select his/her name into a list.

I searched a way to do that and my teacher adviced me to do it with jQuery and AJAX.

So I wrote this :

```js
$(function (carrotcake) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://abc/def/xxx.php",
    }).done(function () {
        $.each(carrotcake, function(key, value) {                
            $('#agent-list').append($("<option></option>").attr("value",key).text(value.AG_NOM + ' ' + value.AG_PRENOM));
        });

        $('#agent-list').change(function (carrotcake) {
            var id = $(this).val();
            if (id != "-1") {
                $('#cd_carsbundle_reservations_nomAgent').val(carrotcake[id].AG_NOM);
                $('#cd_carsbundle_reservations_prenomAgent').val(carrotcake[id].AG_PRENOM);
            } else {
                $('#cd_carsbundle_reservations_nomAgent').val('');
                $('#cd_carsbundle_reservations_prenomAgent').val('');
            }
        })
    })
});
```

And I can see progress. I didn't have results into my list this morning and now I have a lot of undefined undefined.

[image]

OK I progress. Which is good! But I do not understand why I do not have a list of names. Did I forget something? Did I make a typo or something wrong?

Can you help me please?

Comment: So `value.AG_NOM` and `value.AG_PRENOM` are undefined...  And in your code `carrotcake` is referring to jQuery `$(function (carrotcake) {...});`

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to output the data of the API call to your drop-down, then replace the `.done` and `.each` with below snippet.

```
.done(function (data) {
        $.each(data, function(key, value) {
```